# Fractal dimension of landscape generated with Fournier's midpoint algorithm (recursive subdivision) is 2.0 no matter what. Why?

Tags: algorithm

I am using Fournier's midpoint algorithm (recursive subdivision) to construct a landscape of 1025 x 1025 gridpoints, then I am using an advanced version of box counting to find fractal dimension, D. No matter what Hurst exponent I use in Fournier's algorithm, I get D = 2.0. Has anyone checked Fournier's algorithm for fractal dimension? Does it actually produce a fractal?

Comment: Is "Fournier's midpoint algorithm" the [Diamond-square algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm)?

Comment: @Anderson Green Yes.

Comment: This Wikipedia page sums it up pretty well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20more%20specifically%20in,at%20which%20it%20is%20measured.&text=One%20non-trivial%20example%20is,dimension%20of%20a%20Koch%20snowflake.

Comment: @pmw1234 Thank you for providing this wikipedia page with some basic information about fractal dimension. I am not sure how it is relevant for the question asked but thank you anyway.

Comment: "Box Counting" is an overloaded term and your post doesn't give a good context. Perhaps this will help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski–Bouligand_dimension also, when cross posting please link your posts. https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Fournier%27s+midpoint+algorithm

Comment: @pmw1234 Thank you for this very detailed reply. I did not quite understand from your comment whether you have checked Fournier's algorithm for fractal dimension as I was specifically asking in my question but thank you anyway. And of course special thanks for this another very interesting wikipedia page. I will read it when I have time. I am not sure if you want me to edit it or not, though. Hope you will be able to detail on this. I also thank you for pointing out the cross-posting issue - this is indeed crucial for understanding the question I asked.

Comment: @pmw1234 Also, I am very sorry and truly apologize but I did not understand what you mean by "overloaded". Box counting is known to provide an estimate of H which is not very accurate, but still not as inaccurate as would be suggested by the information I supplied in my question. See e.g. the textbook by Peitgen.